# Problema com webscrapping (requests)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Preciso *scrapear* [este site](http://www.cremesc.org.br/buscamedico.jsp) para buscar médicos em uma categoria.

Eu mando a requisição tudo certo, passo o valor (o tipo de médico) e mando via POST a requisição. Porém ele não devolve os valores no código fonte quando eu peço para ver o código fonte pelo Python, mas pelo navegador mostra tudo certinho.

**Meu código**

```
import requests

payload = {"especialidade": "GINECOLOGIA E OBSTETRICIA"}

head = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; 
rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0"}

req = requests.post("http://www.cremesc.org.br/buscamedico.jsp", 
data=payload, headers=head)
print(req.text) #Aqui ja teria que estar as informações dos medicos...
```

**Código por imagem**:

[image: código]

Comment: Cole o código na pergunta, em vez de postar um print,

Comment: [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas — Postar código como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485)

Comment: Perdão sou novo por aqui...